# How to use admin/auth with migrations in multidb project?

Tags: django

It is known issue, that migrations ignore db routing. 
Known solution is to make "manual" routing using parameter --database, and migrate each app separately.

However, when using contrib apps admin/auth/contenttypes, applying a migration fires `post_migrate_signal` that forces them to check extstance of permissions for possibly changed models, and they try to do it in a databasse specified with --database, rather then default.

In particular, I have setup like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'foo',
    'bar'
}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR + '/var/db.sqlite'
    },
    'foo': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'HOST': 'foohost',
        'NAME': 'foo'
    },
    'bar': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': '',
        'NAME': 'bar'
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['DumbDbRouter'] # simply returns app_label as  a target db
```

To run initial migrations of contrib apps, invoke separately:

```
./manage.py migrate auth
./manage.py migrate admin
./manage.py migrate sessions
```

After this, all those contenttypes and permissions are generated for every found model.

Now, running migrations for my app (either initial or sequential):

```
./manage.py migrate foo --database=foo
# fails with error "Error creating new content types.".
```

Trace shows it is raised from attempt to find table `django_contenttypes` in database `foo`.
Now some other operations, like `runserver` will warn: "You have unapplied migrations."

The only workaround I've found is to disable all contrib stuff (including admin urls), then doing migration, and then turn them back.

Consequencies are unclean.

Answer (score 1):

You may handle it using `allow_migrate` method in router. If you application **fooapp** should be in database **foo**, then make sure that **contenttypes** app is also there. For example:

```
class DumbDbRouter(object)
    # ...
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if db == 'foo':
            return app_label in ['fooapp', 'contenttypes']  # <-- PAY ATTENTION
        elif app_label == 'fooapp':
            return False
        return None
```

Read the doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#behavior-of-contrib-apps).

> - each one of **contenttypes.ContentType**, sessions.Session and sites.Site can be stored in any database, **given a suitable router**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you mean I need to distribute content of contenttype table over all the databases?
How could it work?

Comment: You should distribute contentype on each non-default databases wich related to apps (like 'foo') with migrations. It needs for django_migration table (in non-default database) which depends on contenttype tables. By default contenttype tables are stored in default database. In other databases you should store contenttype tables using database router manually.

Comment: referenced docs say, that admin and auth models depends on contenttypes, and should be stored in the same database.  that probably requires replication of auth models in every admined databasse.

Comment: @qMax it depends on app. Have you tried something with router? Does it help?